# Error when Deploying a Google Cloud function (Node JS) using a cloudbuild.yaml

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I have been deploying a google cloud function (Node js) called athenticationProcessing() 
using the following command :

```
gcloud functions deploy athenticationProcessing --runtime nodejs8 --trigger-topic Authentication
```

and so far, it worked fine.
Now i have started cloudbuild i used the following script which also worked fine :

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args:
      - functions
      - deploy
      - athenticationProcessing
      - '--trigger-topic'
      - Authentication
      - '--runtime'
      - nodejs8
      - '--timeout=540'
```

Now i need to create multiple folders where each folder has an index.js and cloud build file (all folders are in one github repo). 
But the cloudbuild.yaml expect the index.js to be in the root folder of the repo.

is there some attribute i can add to make the cloudbuild.yaml know the exact location of my index file instead of guessing the default one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dir` field in each step to specify the particular folder where to execute the deploy command, for example:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args:
      - functions
      - deploy
      - athenticationProcessing
      ...
    dir: folder/foo
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args:
      - functions
      - deploy
      - OTHER_FUNCTION_NAME
      ...
    dir: folder/bar
```

You'll find more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#build_steps).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the `--source` param on the function to define the root directory to deploy.

Comment: You may want to accept the answer if it helped :) And that way other people will see it as solved and helpful.